# How to estimate the storage needed for a database?

Tags: storage, record

I ran across this questions trying to dive into a computer measurements worksheet online and for the life of me could not figure it out. This is the question:

Assume each record in a database requires 1Kib and there should be approximately 5 million records that need to be stored. Estimate the amount of storage needed in gibibytes for the database.

Any help would be extremely appreciated because I'm completely lost on this question even though it sounds like it should be simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's not as simple as 1 KiB × 5 million, then perhaps we would need to take a look at that worksheet before making any suggestion.

Comment: Thats what I dont understand, 1Kib x 5 million or 1024 x 5million? Also I would need to convert it into gibibytes, I'm really new to this so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why not just create a test database and insert some records? I think you'd get a better answer and understanding that way. This isn't a bad question, it's just easy to test on your own with appropriate data.

Comment: 1 KiB = 1024 B, so your two alternatives are the same (if the unit in the second one is implied to be B).

Answer (score 1):

The following would be an ***estimate*** that assumes full pages and doesn't take into consideration any database overhead (page header, etc.) or compression.  It would be simple math

5,000,000kb / 1024 = 4882.8125mb

4882.8125mb / 1024 = 4.76837158203125gb

But, I agree with other comments - you should create a test database and see how close the numbers match up.